# Migrating to preactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, preact

I have a universal react app where server side is built in babel and the client bundle is built in `webpack`. I have read `preact-compact` docs and it suggests to adding this in `.babelrc` for building using `babel`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-react-jsx",
      {
        "pragma": "h"
      }
    ],
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": [
          "."
        ],
        "alias": {
          "react": "preact-compat",
          "react-dom": "preact-compat"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "presets": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

And for `webpack`:

```
{
  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "react": "preact-compat",
      "react-dom": "preact-compat"
    }
  }
}
```

But after building I get an error `h is not defined`

How to migrate to `preact` for a universal react app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But after building i get an error "h is not defined"

You added the `transform-react-jsx` plugin to your babel config.

```
["transform-react-jsx", { "pragma":"h" }]
```

This tells babel how to transpile your JSX code. For that to work, the function `h` needs to be in scope, that means you need to import it in every file you use JSX.

```
import { h } from 'preact';
```

Instead of having to change all your code that uses React, you can use `preact-compat` and alias both `react` and `react-dom` to `preact-compat`, as you did correctly, either with `babel-plugin-module-resolver` or with webpack. With that you can use `react` and `react-dom` in your code and `preact-compat` does the rest for you.

In order to make it work you have to remove `["transform-react-jsx", { "pragma":"h" }]` from your babel config.

Comment: Adding alias in webpack config only solves client bundle issues. But since its a universal app there is server side rendering code as well which gets bundled using babel how to approach that problem

Comment: Ok now I see why you added the `module-resolver` plugin for babel. You did this correctly, you just need to remove the `["transform-react-jsx", { "pragma":"h" }]` and `preact-compat` will do the same as with webpack.

Comment: Yup, @MichaelJungo is right. The "pragma":"h" is for those using preact directly, not via preact-compat.

Comment: After remove `["transform-react-jsx", { "pragma": "h" }],` I received `SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ,` error